# Running multiple jmx files consequently -- how do i add some 'recovery time' between the runs

Tags: load, jmeter

**What i've got:**
 - around 100 jmx files & batch file that executes these jmx files consequently

**The problem is** that after the first jmx-es are run, the system itself gets loaded, so the later jmx-es are run on the loaded system, therefore the results cannot be objective.

That's why i need to add some time between the jmx-es execution, so that the system itself recovers and shows the objective results for the late jmx-es as well as for the first ones.

I've thought about setting some sleep in the batch file, but it looks more like a workaround, not a perfect solution.

I'd be really grateful for any suggestions or hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what operating system you're sitting on here are the options:

- Linux: `sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`
- Windows: use [RAMMap](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx) tool (`Empty` menu option), "Working Sets" should be a good choice

  [image: RAMMap]

Actually well-behaved JMeter test should leave host operating system in the same state as before the test, maybe it is something wrong with the test itself or JMeter is not configured properly? See [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article for some JMeter tuning tips.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you mentioned you were running these from a batch file.. if I were implementing this I would use the

```
thread group
   module controller 1
   module controlelr 2
   module controller x
test fragment 1
test fragment 2
test fragmetn 3
```

This would allow me to use the built in configurations in the "Thread Group" like "ramp up-period (in seconds) 
you could set that to say 5 min... 
or.. you could ping your server to see the system is unloaded... 
If I were working with the dev team id put in a request for a "unload" api call. that you could call in QA or UAT environments to test the system from its unloaded state.

Also There is a "constant Timer" under "Timers" and a "Test action" under "Samplers" which will let you pause the thread. Those could also be solutions depending on your application

Comment: Thanks!
Right now i'm setting the ramp-up value, but.. even thought it could help me not to overload the system, still if i increase my ramp-up period, my tests will loose some of their essence ^^. 

Timers.. right! i was thinking on them, but it seems to me that 'pausing' via timers will not release the cpu, so won't help the last run jmx-es.